# Copied zeros to my external drive, errors reported, is it still safe for daily rsync and which filesystems are safer?

Tags: filesystems, rsync, dd, external-hdd

I had a corrupted file that I suspected to be caused by rsync to and from my aging external mechanical portable HDD.

I made a backup and decided to write zeroes to see if there are writing errors. Sure enough, I got a few but not a lot. See below.

I want to know if this is safe to use for daily rsync between my linux computer and my linux laptop. What file-systems are safe for this, is NTFS unsafe inherently compared to ext4?

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc1 bs=1024
dd: error writing '/dev/sdc1': Input/output error
960119073+0 records in
960119072+0 records out
983161929728 bytes (983 GB, 916 GiB) copied, 51641 s, 19,0 MB/s

$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc1  
smartctl 6.5
2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-109-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke,
www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION === Vendor:               WD Product:              My Passport 0748 Revision:             1019 Compliance:          
SPC-4 User Capacity:        1 000 170 586 112 bytes [1,00 TB] Logical
block size:   512 bytes Rotation Rate:        5400 rpm Serial number: 
WX81A7242861 Device type:          disk Local Time is:        Thu Jan
18 11:30:41 2018 CET SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks
SMART capability.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===

Error Counter logging not supported

No self-tests have been logged


$ dmesg | grep sdc1 
[ 8279.937899]  sdc: sdc1 [21382.527511] Buffer
I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 240030162, lost async page write
[21382.527516] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 240030163,
lost async page write [21382.527518] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1,
logical block 240030164, lost async page write [21382.527524] Buffer
I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 240030165, lost async page write
[21382.527526] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 240030166,
lost async page write [21382.527528] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1,
logical block 240030167, lost async page write [21382.527530] Buffer
I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 240030168, lost async page write
[21382.527532] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 240030169,
lost async page write [21382.527534] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1,
logical block 240030170, lost async page write [21382.527535] Buffer
I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 240030171, lost async page write
[21387.552539] VFS: Dirty inode writeback failed for block device sdc1
(err=-5). [21398.777810]  sdc: sdc1 [21550.843225] EXT4-fs (sdc1):
mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Comment: I don't think so. Check it with `badblocks`or reformat it with `mke2fs -c -c`

Comment: Did you look at full dmesg output without grep? Might just be a cable issue. For `smartctl`, it might still work with one of the `-d` options. https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already had one corrupted file, and there is a known problem with the disk. The problem can either stay the same, or get worse: it is extremely unlikely to "heal". So, **no, it's not safe.**

However, a known-unreliable backup is still (marginally) better than no backup at all: it may allow you to recover at least some of your data if you lose the laptop.

If you keep using this disk, you should attempt to read back all the files you've backed up: maybe not daily, but certainly weekly.

And you should in any case ask yourself:

- How much is the data worth to you? More than the cost of a new disk? About how many times more?
- How much is the *time* needed to recover your data from a failing backup worth to you? In a situation where your laptop is already lost or destroyed? Would it cause you to miss important business? How much stress and anxiety it would cause? Is it worth the risk?

You seem to have a pretty good backup scheme in place (compared to an average laptop owner). You have set it up for a reason. Don't undermine it.

**Update:**

Each `logical block NNNNN, lost async page write` message means the operating system told the disk to write a block of data to the disk, and got back an `I failed to do it properly` from the disk.

This could theoretically mean that just a single bit was flipped in the written output, or that the entire block is now random gibberish. The reality is probably somewhere in between of those two extremes.

Modern disks normally handle write failures transparently by marking the block as failed and using a spare block instead. The fact that the disk is actually reporting the failure back means this spare capacity has already been exhausted: that means there is already a pretty large number of failed blocks on the disk.

Since your `smartctl` command reports:

```
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.
```

there is no way to know further details other than trying to read back all the data, comparing it to the original and counting the errors.

NTFS and ext4 are both pretty resilient filesystem types, but neither can survive indefinitely if the physical storage media is not reliable: if a failure happens at the location of some critical filesystem metadata, entire files or directories may become inaccessible.

The data of those lost files may still be physically present on the disk if it happens to be located on blocks that haven't failed yet, but without the filesystem metadata, you need some data recovery software to find the right blocks corresponding to each missing file. Even then, if the files are fragmented, or using a file format that is not known to the recovery software, there is no 100% guarantee that the recovery software can find exactly the right blocks and re-assemble them into intact files.

Someone said: "Disks are inherently failing machines - data storage is just a side effect." Eventually any spinning disk will fail because of mechanical wear and tear. Portable HDDs are also subjected to way more bumps and jostles than ones installed into desktop or server systems.

Comment: Thanks, I already replaced it with a new external SSD. I wanted a more technical response though. I can't decide if a dd writing error means corrupted disk or not.